# iOS 7: How to turn off camera's burst mode?

Tags: camera, ios

In the stock camera app, iOS 7 has added a new burst mode feature that takes multiple photos in succession for as long as the shutter is pressed. Is there any way I can turn this feature off and have the app behave like the old one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/x-new-and-hidden-settings-in-ios-7), there is no way to turn off burst mode.

> This can be quite handy for catching just the right shot. However, for those of you that had learned to stabilize your camera by holding down the shutter button instead of tapping it, this can result in a lot of unexpected pictures. This feature appears to be enabled full-time whether you want it or not, so we'll all need to simply learn to adapt. Or delete. A lot.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1. Tap the shutter button instead of pressing it for long
2. Use third party camera apps

Comment: Bummer. Holding down the shutter is how I used to get stable shots. First time I used iOS7's, I got a stack of 40 photos, had no idea what was going on.

Comment: you could also try useing the volume button

Comment: As always, there is Apple's feedback hole - http://apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 2):

Currently iOS7 does not allow turning off burst mode when holding on the shutter button. This can be incredibly annoying for those who are used to holding on the shutter button and releasing to capture a shot in motion or taking a selfie. Also, you now need to be very careful when handing your camera to someone to take your picture as they may shoot off 20-30 images without knowing. Also, even with your flash set to 'on' the camera app does not wait for the flash to recharge and will shoot off many unusable images between flash cycles.